# cmake add_custom_command + Xcode: multi output = multi command invocation

Tags: c++, c, xcode, macos, cmake

I have custom command that generate several headers at once.
All works fine with make/ninja files generated by cmake.
But if I generate Xcode project via `cmake -GXCode`,
then instead of once `gen.sh` was invoked 10 times
and not only that, it also will be invoked every build,
even if timestamps of generated file are younger then gen_in.txt.

How can I fix this?

```
project(multi_output)
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.17)

set(MANY_HEADERS test0.h test1.h  test2.h  test3.h  test4.h  test5.h  test6.h  test7.h  test8.h  test9.h)

add_custom_command(
  OUTPUT ${MANY_HEADERS}
  COMMAND ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/gen.sh
  DEPENDS gen_in.txt
  WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}
  )

add_executable(foo main.cpp ${MANY_HEADERS})
```

where gen.sh is

```sh
#!/bin/sh

echo "gen.sh: start"
sleep 1
echo "gen.sh: hard work done"
for i in `seq 0 9`; do
    cat gen_in.txt > test$i.h
    sed -i bak s/placeholder/$i/g test$i.h
done
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `OUTPUT` option *relative paths* are treated as relative to the **binary directory**.

That is, your `add_custom_command` actually doesn't produce the files declared as OUTPUT.

This is why it is called more and more: the build tool finds out that an OUTPUT file does not exist, and runs the COMMAND for build that file. (Many build tool don't check whether the OUTPUT file is *actually* created.)

For files created in the *source directory* you need to specify their **absolute path** in `OUTPUT` option:

```
set(MANY_HEADERS test0.h test1.h  test2.h  test3.h  test4.h  test5.h  test6.h  test7.h  test8.h  test9.h)
# This will be a list of _absolute paths_ to the headers
set(MANY_HEADERS_ABS)

foreach(HEADER ${MANY_HEADERS})
  list(APPEND MANY_HEADERS_ABS "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/${HEADER}")
endforeach()

add_custom_command(
  OUTPUT ${MANY_HEADERS_ABS}
  COMMAND ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/gen.sh
  DEPENDS gen_in.txt
  WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}
  )

# In add_executable one could use relative paths too
add_executable(foo main.cpp ${MANY_HEADERS})
```

---

Note, that `add_executable` command may accept *relative paths* to the file both in source and binary trees.

CMake checks whether a file exists or generated (e.g. with `add_custom_command`) in the source tree, and if it is, the source path is used. Then similar checks are performed for binary tree. (And if this check fails, CMake will emit an error).

---

Actually, careful inspecting of the `make` output may give a hint, whether `make` rebuilds files in the *source* tree or in the *build* tree.

This is what is produced by the original code (remember: `make` is called from the *build* directory):

```
[ 33%] Generating test0.h, test1.h, test2.h, test3.h, test4.h, test5.h, test6.h, test7.h, test8.h, test9.h
```

And this is what is produced when use absolute paths to the source tree. (Out-of-source build, use `build/` subdirectory for build.)

```
[ 33%] Generating ../test0.h, ../test1.h, ../test2.h, ../test3.h, ../test4.h, ../test5.h, ../test6.h, ../test7.h, ../test8.h, ../test9.h
```